# Create a Vector with a Value Node as each value

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes, vector

I want to create a *Vector Node* in *Geometry Nodes* but with each value being driven by a separate *Value Node*.

**Like this:**

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use a *Combine XYZ*?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the "Combine xyz"-node, which you can find here:

[image]